# Отобрать элементы в массиве по набору значений из другого массива Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть основной массив и массив условие:

```
const objects = [
  { id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" },
  { id: "56", naim: "Объект 2", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "57", naim: "Объект 3", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "58", naim: "Объект 4", iduser: "17" },
];
const spisok = ["55","57"];
```

Нужно получить фильтр из основного массива по условию из spisok, связывая по полю id, такого содержания:

```
[
  { id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" },
  { id: "57", naim: "Объект 3", iduser: "22" },
]
```

Пытался родить что-то типа:

```
const result = spisok.map((u) =>
  objects.filter((a) => 
    (a.id == u)
  )
);
```

Но так получается один лишний уровень.

ЗЫ И еще вопрос: если массив-условие будет объект такого типа:

```
const spisok = {id: ["55","57"], iduser: ["17"] };
```

Чтобы отобрало все объекты где id (55, 57) и iduser (17).
Результат будет только:

```
{ id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" }.
```

Comment: Вам просто код написать?

Comment: Да, я по нему разберусь, что к чему и учту на будущее

Comment: Вы уже прочитали вот эту статью? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Да, я понимаю как работет Array.prototype.filter(). Но у меня проблемы с проверкой, когда условие массив

Comment: Код - в вопрос. Ссылка "Править" - под вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const objects = [
  { id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" },
  { id: "56", naim: "Объект 2", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "57", naim: "Объект 3", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "58", naim: "Объект 4", iduser: "17" },
];
const spisok = ["55","57"];

const result = objects.filter(i => spisok.includes(i.id));
console.log(result);
```

```js
const objects = [
  { id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" },
  { id: "56", naim: "Объект 2", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "57", naim: "Объект 3", iduser: "22" },
  { id: "58", naim: "Объект 4", iduser: "17" },
];
const spisok = {
  id: ["55","57"], 
  iduser: ["17"] 
};

const result = objects.filter(i => {
  const entries = Object.entries(spisok);
  return entries.filter(e => e[1].includes(i[e[0]])).length == entries.length;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо то, что нужно. Нужно еще раз перечитать все методы. А можно ли будет отфильтровать objects, если в spisok будет немного сложнее массив: const spisok = {id: ["55","57"], iduser: ["17"] };
Чтобы отобрало все объекты где id (55, 57) и iduser  (17). Результат будет только { id: "55", naim: "Объект 1", iduser: "17" }. При этом на входе не ясно какие поля будут в условия.

Comment: @merlinby Можно. Второй фрагмент.